Fundamental group of a twisted torus
Let $X$ be the space obtained as the quotient of a cylinder by gluing the two boundary
circles by wrapping one twice around the other (i.e., think of each boundary circle as the
unit circle in the complex plane and the gluing map from one of the circles to the other is
given by $z \mapsto z^2$). Compute the fundamental group of $X$.
This problem is from an old final exam. I think this should be a straightforward application of Van-Kampen's theorem, but I could not figure out what open cover to use. So I tried to draw an identification diagram as attached, which suggests that $\pi_1(x) = \langle a,b,c \mid ab^{-1}c^{-1}ac^{-1} \rangle$, since the diagram is obtained by gluing a $2-$cell along the only relator listed.
I am not convinced that this is a correct solution, however. This is because at copy of $S^1$ where the two ends of the cylinder is identified, locally it looks like a "book with $3$ pages," which is not a $2-$ manifold, so it should not be possible to obtain $X$ by an identification diagram.
What am I missing here?
An alternative solution to the original problem would also be appreciated.

Note that your presentation gives a free group on $2$ generators (you can eliminate $b$ using the one relator). One way of doing this is to build the universal cover, and look for the deck transformations.

You can also do this with van Kampen's theorem, but the details take some work. $U$ can be the whole space minus the glued circle. $V$ can be the half of the space containing the glued circle, together with a thin strand connecting the two boundary pieces (this strand ensures $U\cap V$ is connected). The result should be a group with two generators and one relator.

@SteveD Is the solution I presented above correct?

No it's not a free group. You can draw a diagram of this that might help you see what the fundamental group is (the same way you can read the fundamental group of a torus from the boundary of a square). You can probably also make that argument formal as well. Edit: actually you have already drawn that diagram in your picture (1).

@SteveD So the mistake was in reading off the group presentation from figure 5?

I think the mistake is in figure 2: your cut doesn't respect the identifications. I'm not sure if you can cut and paste in this case. You could try arguing about the CW complex structure on your space, where you can read the presentation off from the 1-skeleton and 2-skeleton.

I believe the mistake is actually in the transition from figure $3$ to $4$. In $(3)$, all three “$b$” edges must be identified. You’ve glued two of them in $(4)$, but not all of them, and figure $(4)$ has forgotten that the other $b$ must be glued to the same line. You’ve drawn two bold dots at the start of the leftmost $c$ and $a$ edges: imagine a line connecting those dots; $b$ must be glued with that line. The result is a cylinder with a triangular flap with the $c,a$ edges on the triangle being identified with the bottom, top circles of the cylinder respectively

@SteveD I computed: $$\pi_1\cong\langle,\alpha,\beta,|,\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha^2,\rangle$$Do you agree? Hopefully you found an isomorphic presentation

Yes that's the presentation.

Actually, your figure $(1)$ is good enough. As I commented, in your figures $(3)-(4)$ there is a mistake in that the remaining “$b$” edge in $(4)$ has to be identified with the other two, but they’ve disappeared! You’re missing a gluing line. In figure $(1)$, you can already see a CW structure on the square given by the $1$-skeleton of a pentagon and attaching a disc on its interior; applying the quotient map, since it is suitably compatible with this cell structure (rigorously, it is easy to use the cellulation theorem just under the definitions here, or as given by Hatcher in his appendix, applied to cell maps to the pentagon composed with the quotient and easily noting your space is Hausdorff) you cellulate the desired twisted torus.
The $1$-skeleton consists of a vertex and two loops $a,b$ and the attached $2$-cell’s boundary loop is homotopic with the composition $aba^{-1}b^{-2}$. By a well known procedure for computing the fundamental group of a space with two cells attached (given in Hatcher $1.2$ if I’m not mistaken) - which incidentally makes heavy use of Seifert van Kampen - you obtain the presentation $\langle\,a,b\,|\,ab=b^2a\,\rangle$.
There’s no manifold issue. There is no theorem that every quotient of a disc by an equivalence relation acting only on boundary points has to be a manifold.
I think it’s hard to directly apply SvK here due to the requirement the sets must contain the same basepoint and have path connected intersections. It is quite straightforward to partition this space for a homology computation (Mayer Victoris) as we can be much more flexible.

Here is the van Kampen argument. I present it here just to show how it can be done, but also to convince you that it's usually not worth it :)
Let $\rho:S^1\times[0,1]\rightarrow X$ be the quotient map, and let $W$ be a small open contractible neighborhood of $1\in S^1$. We need to define path-connected open subsets $U$, $V$, and $U\cap V$ of $X$, such that $X=U\cup V$. I will use the basepoint $x=\rho(1,\tfrac{1}{2})$.
We can take $U=\rho(S^1\times(0,1))$, which is the image of an open saturated subset, hence open in $X$. The fundamental group $\pi_1(U,x)\cong\langle\alpha\rangle$ is free on one generator ($U$ deformation retracts to a circle), represented by the loop $a:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ given by
\begin{equation}
a(t) = \rho(e^{2\pi it},\tfrac{1}{2})
\end{equation}
For $V$, we take the union
\begin{equation}
V = \rho(S^1\times[0,\tfrac{1}{3}))\bigcup \rho(S^1\times(\tfrac{2}{3},1])\bigcup\rho(W\times[0,1])
\end{equation}
$V$ is also the image of an open saturated subset, so is also open in $X$. The fundamental group $\pi_1(V,x)\cong\langle\beta,\gamma\rangle$ is free on two generators ($V$ deformation retracts to the wedge of two circles), represented by loops
\begin{align}
 b(t) &= \begin{cases}
 \rho(1,t+\tfrac{1}{2}) & t\le\tfrac{1}{2}\\
 \rho(1,t-\tfrac{1}{2}) & t\ge\tfrac{1}{2}
\end{cases} &\qquad c(t) &= \begin{cases}
\rho(1,\tfrac{1}{2}-t) & t\le\tfrac{1}{4}\\
\rho(e^{4\pi i(t-1/4)},\tfrac{1}{4}) & \tfrac{1}{4}\le t\le\tfrac{3}{4}\\
\rho(1,t-\tfrac{1}{2}) & t\ge\tfrac{3}{4}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Think of $b(t)$ as looping around the circle $\rho(1\times[0,1])$ and $c(t)$ as following a path from $x$ into $S^1\times\{\tfrac{1}{4}\}$, then doing a loop there, then going back to $x$. We thus have our generators for $\pi_1(X,x)$: $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$.
Finally, $U\cap V$ can be expressed explicitly by removing the "endpoints" of $V$:
\begin{equation}
U\cap V = \rho(S^1\times(0,\tfrac{1}{3}))\bigcup \rho(S^1\times(\tfrac{2}{3},1))\bigcup\rho(W\times(0,1))
\end{equation}
$U\cap V$ also deformation retracts to two circles, and so has fundamental group $\pi_1(U\cap V,x)\cong\langle\delta,\epsilon\rangle$. To represent $\delta$, we can take the loop $c(t)$ above, which is homotopic to $a(t)$ in $U$. So this introduces the relation $\alpha=\gamma$. The generator $\epsilon$ is also represented by $a(t)$ in $U$. In $V$, it is represented by the concatenated path $b\cdot c^2\cdot b^{-1}(t)$. The conjugation by $b(t)$ here allows one to define a homotopy around the circle $\rho(1\times[0,1])$. Meanwhile, we use $c^2$ because when this double loop passes through $\rho(S^1\times\{1\})$, it becomes a single loop.
I encourage you to draw a picture of this. There's enough detail here to make this formal, but the picture makes it very clear what's going on.
So $\epsilon$ gives the final relation $\alpha=\beta\gamma^2\beta^{-1}$, so by van Kampen's theorem we have
\begin{equation}
\pi_1(X,x)\cong\langle\alpha,\beta,\gamma\mid\alpha=\gamma,\alpha=\beta\gamma^2\beta^{-1}\rangle\cong\langle\beta,\gamma\mid\gamma=\beta\gamma^2\beta^{-1}\rangle
\end{equation}
