Fundamental group of a double cover cylinder
I am having a bit of a hard time figuring out the fundamental group of this space: take a cylinder, then glue its boundaries (two copies of $S^1$) using the double cover map.  I know that this group is isomorphic to the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$, but I don't understand why.
I saw this post which helped me visualize the space:
Mapping cylinder of $z\rightarrow z^2$
, but I am not sure how to compute the fundamental group from that. Any help would be appreciated.

Some prior art: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4960609/265452

Also, your semidirect product (at least the notation) is wrong. $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ is the normal subgroup.

Does the diagram 1 at the "prior" art show to you how (starting from the lower-left corner of that diagram) $a$ then $b$ is the same as $b^2$ then $a$?  That is, $ab = b^2 a$.  To rephrase, sliding a $b$-loop along what was the longitudinal direction on the cylinder in the $a^{-1}$ direction yields two $b$-loops (on the quotient).  Then $aba^{-1} = b^2$ and you have the conjugation you need to define your semidirect product.

Regarding the comment of @SteveD, keep in mind that semidirect product is an symmetric operation. The asymmetry is enforced either by notation $\mathbb Z[1/2] \rtimes \mathbb Z$ or by language, the "semidirect product of $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ by $\mathbb Z$".

There's a two step proof, which I can write out later if I have the time: first use (the simplest possible) CW complex of that space to get the presentation $\langle a,t \mid tat^{-1}=a^2 \rangle$ (see one of the answers of the linked post); then prove that the latter group has a $\mathbb Z[1/2]$-by-$\mathbb Z$ semidirect product structure. One can be even more specific: it is isomorphic to the group of $2 \times 2$ matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 2^k & m/2^n \ 0 & 2^{-k} \end{pmatrix}$, $m,n,k \in \mathbb Z$; the homomorphism to $\mathbb Z$ simply reads off the value of $k$.

You can also see the semidirect product structure in the deck transformations of the universal cover $\mathbb{R}^2$. They are generated by $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y+1)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto(x+1,2y)$. You can show all "purely vertical" translations form a normal subgroup, and then read off $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1}{2}]$ from the possible vertical translation amounts.

@Steve D: $\mathbb R^2$ is not the universal cover of anything having that fundamental group. The action you describe is not properly discontinuous, as deck actions are required to be.

@LeeMosher: yes, you're right. The group acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it's not a covering space action.

In my first comment there is a bad typo: the occurrence of the word "symmetric" should be "asymmetric".

As a first step, the post you linked, particularly the answer of @Dmitri, gives a very clear description of a CW decomposition of your space, with two edges that I'll label $t$ and $a$, and with a 2-cell attached by mapping its boundary to the path $t a t^{-1} a^{-1} a^{-1}$. This tells you that the fundamental group has presentation
$$\langle a,t \mid tat^{-1}=a^2 \rangle
$$
This is a semi-famous group, the solvable Baumslag-Solitar group of type $BS(1,2)$.
The next step is to prove that this group is isomorphic to group of matrices
$$\Gamma = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 2^m & n \, / \,  2^k \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \, \mid \, m,n,k \in \mathbb Z \right\}
$$
It's easy to see that this group is a semidirect product of the form $\mathbb Z[1/2] \rtimes_\phi \mathbb Z$: the homomorphism to $\mathbb Z$ is obtained by reading off the exponent $m$; and the kernel of this homomorphism has $2^0=1$ in the upper left entry and $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ in the upper right entry.
You can use matrix multiplication to check that under the mapping $a \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $t \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, the equation $ta=a^2t$ holds. Therefore we obtain a homomorphism
$$\langle a,t \mid tat^{-1}=a^2 \rangle \mapsto \Gamma
$$
It's also not too hard to mess around with matrix products to prove that these two matrices generate $\Gamma$. So this homomorphism is surjective.
The work that's left is to verify that the kernel of this homomorphism is the identity. So, suppose you have a word $w$ in $a$'s and $t$'s whose image is the identity matrix. The job is to show that $w$ can be reduced to the empty word by successive application of the relator $tat^{-1}=a^2$. The idea is simple: push $t$'s to the right; and push $t^{-1}$'s to the right. That is:
Push $t$'s to the right:

Wherever you see a subword $ta$, replace it by the equivalent word $a^2 t$.
Wherever you see a $t a^{-1}$, replace it by the equivalent word $a^{-2} t$.

Push $t^{-1}$'s to the left:

Wherever you see a subword $at^{-1}$, replace it by the equivalent word $t^{-1} a^2$.

Wherever you see a subword $a^{-1} t^{-1}$, replace it by the equivalent word $t^{-1} a^{-2}$.


As you go along, automatically do all trivial cancellations, that is, cancel $tt^{-1}$, cancel $a^{-1}a$, etc.
When you are done, your arbitrary starting word will have been rewritten to have the following form
$$t^{-m} a^k t^n
$$
Since this group element is in the kernel of the map to $\Gamma$, it follows that $m=n$ and $k=0$ and so the word cancels down to the empty word.

One last thing to say: the matrix group $\Gamma$ acts on the upper half plane $\mathbb H = \{z = x+iy \in \mathbb C \mid y > 0\}$ by fractional linear transformations. This action is free but not properly discontinuous (this is related to a discussion in the comments). Understanding and visualizing this action is what led me to this proof.
